# Will all the models of this FOL theory represent only bipartite graphs ? And viceversa?

Tags: graph-theory, first-order-logic, bipartite-graphs

Will all the models of the following formula be bipartite graphs, with edges being represented by $R$ and $A$ and $\neg A$ being two disjoint groups of vertices ?

$$\forall x \forall y R(x,y) \rightarrow (\neg A(x) \leftrightarrow A(y))$$

Is this encoding right ?

Comment: No. For example if $A(x_0)$ and $\neg A(x_1)$, then it is not necessarily the case that $R(x_0,x_1)$.

Comment: aaah I see I am sorry I guess I wrote an inconsistent theory. But do you think we can write bipartite graphs in FOL ?

Comment: Yes, certainly! I was just giving a counter example to your characterization. I would start by changing your biconditional to an implication.

Comment: @Couchy What do you say now ?

Comment: I just realized I don't have the same notion of bipartite graph as you, since it seems you require that every vertex has a neighbour. In this case, your original two formulas were correct, apologies!

Comment: No the problem there was R(x,x), which would have led to in-concistency,

Comment: Is this one incorrect in your opinion ? In your definition of bipartite, I think $\forall x \forall y R(x,y) \rightarrow (\neg A(x) \leftrightarrow A(y))$  would be enough I guess.

Comment: Probably. To prove it, take a model (that is a set $V$, predicate $A$, and relation $R$) and show that it is a graph, and necessarily bipartite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally speaking, I think YES: all models (i.e. value assignments of $R$ and $A$) of your FOL formula are bipartite graphs (together with their bipartitions). In other words, each $R$ and $A$ satisfying your formula is indeed a bipartite graph $G(V,R)$ and $A$ is a bipartition of this graph (there may exist more than one bipartitions if there are isolated vertices in the graph). Of course, to be more precise we should assume a vertex set $V$ and your formula should be written as $\forall x \in V, y \in V. R(x,y) \rightarrow (\neg A(x) \leftrightarrow A(y))$.

But this does not mean that bipartition (or in general k-colorability) is *expressible* in FOL. In fact, it's only expressible in MSO (or more expressible logics), where your $A$ is a set variable as existential quantifiers: $G(V,R)$ is bipartite iff $\exists A \subset V. \forall x \in V, y \in V. R(x,y) \rightarrow (\neg A(x) \leftrightarrow A(y))$.

Or maybe we can see it in this way: given any $R$ and $A$, your FOL formula can be used to test if $R$ is a bipartite graph *with $A$ as its bipartition*.  If the test succeeds (e.g. by loop over all edges in $R$), for sure $R$ is a bipartite graph. But if the test failed, it does not mean that $R$ is not a bipartite graph, because it could be that the $A$ part is wrong - it's not a bipartition. For instance, if we use a bipartition graph $R$ and the set of all vertices $V$ to test your formula, the formula will obviously fail, and thus this pair ($R$ and $V$) is not a model of the formula. But (by assumption) still $R$ is a bipartite graph.

In summary, just because your FOL formula doesn't give a one-one correspondence of any single input $R$ and the bipartite property of it, this FOL formula cannot be used to express (or define) bipartite graphs. Yet your original question indeed has a YES answer, just it cannot conclude that your graph property (bipartition here) is FOL-expressible.

Answer (score 1):

All models will be bipartite graphs. However, "are all bipartite graphs models?" is complicated to answer.

You've demonstrated that *bipartitions* are expressible in first-order logic. That is, given a graph (specified by a relation $R$) and a predicate $A$, we get a partition of the vertex set into two parts: those for which $A$ holds, and those for which $A$ does not hold. Then we can express the statement "This partition is a bipartition of the graph" in first-order logic, which is essentially what you've done.

This is different from the statement "The graph is bipartite" or "The graph has *some* bipartition." To build from the axioms in the question to such a statement, we'd need to begin with "There exists a predicate $A$ such that ..." which is not allowed in first-order logic.

We can get closer. A graph is bipartite if and only if it does not have any odd cycles. For any fixed $n$, we can express the statement "The graph does not have any cycles of length $2n+1$" in first-order logic. So with infinitely many axioms, we can express "A graph is bipartite" just by combining these statements for $n=1,2,3,\dots$.

With finitely many axioms we can't get there. I don't have the technical know-how to explain why, but the intuitive idea is that any finite set of axioms only works on some "local" scale. For large enough $n$, $C_{2n+1}$ will be indistinguishable from a bipartite graph on that scale, because you have to go all the way around the very long odd cycle to notice that the graph is not bipartite.

Comment: A first order theory may be specified with predicate and relation symbols. So it suffices to show that the models of the theory specified by the OP (except for $\forall x.\exists y. R(x,y)$, which seem to exclude isolated vertices) are graphs with no cycles of odd length.

Comment: @Couchy True, but typically when we are asking "Is <graph property> expressible in first-order logic?" we assume that we are working in the first-order theory *of graphs*, which does not have an extra predicate $A$.

Comment: (A related point is that a graph-plus-extra-predicate-$A$ which does not satisfy the axioms specified by the OP may still be a bipartite graph, if $A$ happens not to correspond to its bipartition.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov why would that ever happen ? If R(x,y) is true then only y is in A and x is not in A. And thats a bipartition. What I want to do is to write a theory for which each interpretation is only a bipartite graph. This theory does not have to point to a particular bipartition, but all bipartitions have to be consistent with it. Do you think even that is not achievable in FOL ?

Comment: I have changed the problem to make it disjoint from what I think that you think the problem is ? Is it better now ?

Comment: @SagarM Suppose that we have (for three vertices $1,2,3$) that $R(1,2), R(2,3)$ hold and $A(1), A(2)$ hold, but not any others. Then the graph is bipartite, but because $A$ is wrong, the formula does not hold.

Comment: How can A(1) ,A(2) and R(1,2) all hold in a bipartite graph ?

Comment: Well, the graph is bipartite because putting $\{1,3\}$ on one side and $\{2\}$ on the other makes for a bipartition. The predicate $A$ doesn't match that bipartition, but changing $A$ doesn't change whether the *graph* has a property or not.